# What does "renames" mean in the list of tag synonyms?

Tags: support, tag-synonyms

What does the number in the column named *renames* in the [list of tag synonyms](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/tags/synonyms) mean?

Is it the number of questions that were tagged with the "child tag" when the synonym was created?

Answer (score 9, accepted):

It represents the number of times that someone has entered that tag and it was retagged to the master tag since the synonym was created.

So for example, given the relationship [tag-synonyms](/questions/tagged/tag-synonyms) ← [tag-synonym](/questions/tagged/tag-synonym), if I explicitly type out "tag-synonym" and hit space to format it as a tag, that tag will be remapped to the master tag. That will increase the count for renames, and update the "last"column as being the last time a rename occurred for that relationship.

It's basically a way of tracking how often users are typing out that specific synonym and having it remapped to whatever master tag it points to. A lot of synonyms, like [tag-synonym](/questions/tagged/tag-synonym), don't get many renames recorded because most users will select the master tag when it pops up in the tag suggestions and the actual tag rename never occurs.

Comment: Thanks for your answer! If two existing tags are synonymized, is this counter set to zero, or is the initial value the number of questions in the "child tag"?

Comment: The number always starts at 0. When tags get synonymized, the questions under the slave tag do not get retagged by default. If a moderator merges them, those do not count as renames. But if a user edits the question without changing the tag to the master tag, then it will get renamed upon saving those edits and *that* would count as a rename.